# Frontend exposed via ingress can't access internal API service in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm banging my head against the wall on this issue:
there is frontend app exposed via ingress (app.testing.com) and API service in "microservices" namespace. I can't really tie that together. I've ended exposing API via Ingress (api.testing.com) but there must be a way to do this in more secure, internal fashion.

Errors:

`'https://app.testing.tech/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.microservices.svc.cluster.local/auth/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api.microservices.svc.cluster.local:80/auth/login' from origin 'https://app.testing.tech' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, isolated-app, arc, https, chrome-untrusted, data, chrome-extension, chrome.`

These error are mostly based on what ENV for backend I set (with, or without HTTP or HTTPS).

Any idea, why is that? Or what I'm missing here?

YAML for app:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: apps
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: app.testing.tech
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "DNT, Keep-Alive, User-Agent, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Content-Type, Range, Authorization, Cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-expose-headers: "*"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app.testing.tech
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: app
            port:
              number: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - app.testing.tech
    secretName: app-tls-secret
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: apps
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: github-registry
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: ghcr.io/testing/app:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: apps
spec:
  selector:
    app: app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
```

YAML for backend

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api
  namespace: microservices
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: api
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: github-registry
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: ghcr.io/testing/api:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api
  namespace: microservices
spec:
  selector:
    app: api
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

I've tried using service-meshes, like Istio and VirtualServices, but no luck.

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

Your frontend is running inside the browser of the user. It can not access services inside the cluster without an Ingress that makes them available externally.